# WMC005 Cannot assign text value of '0' into property 'Value' of type 'Byte'

Tags: winui-3, winui

As can be seen in the error message, the `TypeConverter` is apparently ignored. Do I have an error in usage or why am I getting this XAML error message?

*Please refrain from showing me another way how to bind a byte to the ComboBox. I deleted all superfluous code to make the example here as simple as possible. In my application, the base class is significantly more complex.*

Thanks very much!

```xml
<ComboBox>
  <comboBox:ComboBoxByteItem Value="0"/>
  <comboBox:ComboBoxByteItem Value="1"/>
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

```cs
public class FooConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) => sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string text)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return byte.Parse(text);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is byte b)
            return b.ToString();
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass
{

}

public class ComboBoxByteItem : MyBaseClass
{
    private byte _value;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
    public byte Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value != null && _value.Equals(value))
                return;
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Haprotec.WinUI.UI.ControlStation</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5886-->
    <WinUISDKReferences>false</WinUISDKReferences>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>
    <GenerateLibraryLayout>true</GenerateLibraryLayout>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `TypeConverter`s in **WinUI 3**. There is an open discussion in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3896) though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had overlooked the issue on GitHub.. ‍♂️